# Newton method for transcendental equation

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods

Transcendental equation:
tan(x)/x + b = 0, where b is any real number.
I need to introduce n and give me n solutions of this equation.

My code (Python):

```
    from math import tan, cos, pi, sqrt, sin,exp
    import numpy as np 
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def f(x,b):
        return tan(x)/x + b

    def f1(x,b):
        return (x/(cos(x)*cos(x)) - tan(x))/(x**2)

    e = 0.00000000001

    def newtons_method(x0, f, f1, e):
        x0 = float(x0)
        while True:
            x1 = x0 - (f(x0,b) / f1(x0,b))
            if abs(x1 - x0) < e:
                return x1
            x0 = x1

    result = []
    n = int(input("Input n: "))
    b = float(input("Input b: "))
    for i in range(2,4*n,1):
        result.append(newtons_method(i, f , f1, e))
    lambda_result = sorted(list(set(result)))
    print(len(lambda_result))
```

I change the initial approximation with step 1.The roots are repeated with a period of ~pi, so the second argument 4*n. I exclude repeated solutions through set. If n is 50 then he finds only 18 solution. What needs to be fixed to make it work? Help me, please.

Comment: import? write them!

Comment: there is The value of n?

Comment: @Jundullah values n and b are entered in the graphical interface

Comment: why didn't you specify other variables. Edit post !

Comment: Try converting to Decimal over float?

Shot in the dark. Edit: Even double possibly.

Comment: @Jundullah yes, added

Comment: 1) What value of `b` causes `n=50` to give only 18 solutions, and what happens to the other 32 solutions (error, repeated, other)? You are expected on this site to be more precise just where and how your code does not work. 2) Must you use Newton(-Raphson)? That method is not guaranteed to work. Could you use a combination of that method with bisection, which is guaranteed to work?

Comment: @RoryDaulton 1) b = 2, 2) can show this combination?

Comment: @RoryDaulton roots repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cross-post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2942400/115115 it was strongly recommended by Yves Daoust to base your Newton method on the function

```
f(x)=sin(x) + b*x*cos(x)
```

or

```
f(x)=sin(x)/x + b*cos(x)
```

as these functions do not have poles or other singularities (if x is not close to 0).

The solutions are, at least for large `c`, close to the initial values `(i+0.5)*pi for i in range(n)`. The result does then not require sorting or shortening of the result.

One could use that at the roots of the cosine the sine term has alternating sign. This makes a perfect situation to apply a *bracketing method* like **regula falsi (illinois), Dekker's fzeroin, Brent's method**,... These methods are almost as fast as the Newton method and are guaranteed to find the root inside the interval.

The only complication is the interval `(0,pi/2)` as there will be a non-zero root for `b<-1`. One has to remove the root-finding process from `x=0` which is non-trivial for `b` close to `-1`.

---

**Newton's method** only zero's in to the root reliably when the initial point is close enough to the root. If the point is farther away, close to an extremum of the function, the root of the tangent may be very far away. Thus to successfully apply the Newton method, one needs to find good root approximations from the start. To that end one may use globally convergent fixed-point iterations or structurally simple approximations of the function under consideration.

- Using the contracting fixed-point iteration: the solution around `k*pi` is also a root of the equivalent equation `x+arctan(b*x)=k*pi`. This gives the approximate solution `x=g(k*pi)=k*pi-arctan(b*k*pi)`. As the arcus tangent is rather flat even for small `k`, this gives a good approximation.
- If `b<-1` there is a positive root for `k=0`, that is in the interval `(0,pi/2)`. The previous method does not work in this case as the arcus tangent has a slope around `1` in this interval. The root is due to the higher order, non-linear terms of the equation, so one needs a non-linear approximation of one of the equivalent forms of the equation. Approximating `tan(x)=x/(1-(2*x/pi)^2)` gives the same poles at `+-pi/2` and is sufficiently close in between. Inserting this approximation into the given equation and solving gives the initial root approximation at `x=pi/2*sqrt(1+1/b)`.

In the implementation one has to shift the root set for `b<-1` to include the additional first solution.

```
from math import tan, cos, pi, sqrt, sin, atan

def f(x,b):
    return sin(x)/x+b*cos(x)

def f1(x,b):
    return cos(x)/x-(b+x**-2)*sin(x)

e = 1e-12

def newtons_method(x0, f, f1, e):
    x0 = float(x0)
    while True:
        x1 = x0 - (f(x0,b) / f1(x0,b))
        if abs(x1 - x0) < e:
            return x1
        x0 = x1

result = []
n = int(input("Input n: "))
b = float(input("Input b: "))
for i in range(n):
    k=i; 
    if b >= -1: k=k+1
    x0 = pi/2*sqrt(1+1/b) if k==0 else  k*pi-atan(b*k*pi)
    result.append(newtons_method(x0, f , f1, e))
lambda_result = sorted(list(set(result)))
print(len(result), len(lambda_result))
```

Comment: @ LutzL breaks when small c. Can this be eliminated?

Comment: How small and what n? For b=+-1e-8 I find no problems.

Comment: Input n: 50
Input b: 0.001
50 42

Comment: With closer approximations of the initial values that goes away.

Comment: Everything works, thank you. I'm trying to understand why the initial approximations are like that. Could you write about them in more detail?Editing your answer to  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2942400/115115. I would be very grateful.