# Find positive roots numerically

Tags: python, math, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods

How to solve this equation for positive E numerically for a given M value? I tried the FindRoot method in Mathematica, but it never converged to a correct solution. Here, M is any positive real number. My goal is to plot the curve M vs E.

`Sqrt[E]*Cos[Sqrt[E]]=-M*Sin[Sqrt[E]]`

Comment: I notice that's equivalent to `x cos(x) = - M sin(x)` for `x` equal to `sqrt(E)`, and that's equivalent to `- x / M = tan(x)`. So you can find x and then `E = x^2` from that. I think there are going to be a lot of solutions -- the line `- x / M` intersects with `tan(x)` over and over. Try plotting that before looking for numerical solutions. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @Seyi Daniel  This is a root-finding problem, LHS be exactly equal to RHS. M can be any non-negative number, in particular, I'm interested in M between 0 and 1.

Comment: After the proposed transformations this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669755/newton-method-for-transcendental-equation/52671224#52671224

Comment: Did any of the proposed answers help you out?

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to plot M against E, use

```
M = - √E cot(√E).
```

[image]

Comment: Nice plot, thanks. But my goal is to plot E against M. Any help?

Comment: Come on, don't you know the relation between inverse graphs ?

Comment: Is this function invertible?

Comment: @mathlover: obviously not !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method with Mathematica that seems to work:

```
In[37]:= FindRoot[x + 1/10 Tan[x], {x, # + Abs[#]*10^-14, (# + Pi) (1. - 10^-14)}, Method -> "Brent"] & /@ Range[-Pi/2, 50 Pi, Pi]
Out[37]= {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 1.63199}, {x -> 4.73351}, {x -> 7.86669},
          {x -> 11.0047}, {x -> 14.1442}, {x -> 17.2845}, {x -> 20.4252},
          {x -> 23.5662}, {x -> 26.7073}, {x -> 29.8485}, {x -> 32.9898},
          {x -> 36.1311}, {x -> 39.2725}, {x -> 42.4139}, {x -> 45.5553},
          {x -> 48.6967}, {x -> 51.8382}, {x -> 54.9797}, {x -> 58.1212},
          {x -> 61.2627}, {x -> 64.4042}, {x -> 67.5457}, {x -> 70.6872},
          {x -> 73.8288}, {x -> 76.9703}, {x -> 80.1119}, {x -> 83.2534},
          {x -> 86.395}, {x -> 89.5365}, {x -> 92.6781}, {x -> 95.8196},
          {x -> 98.9612}, {x -> 102.103}, {x -> 105.244}, {x -> 108.386},
          {x -> 111.527}, {x -> 114.669}, {x -> 117.811}, {x -> 120.952},
          {x -> 124.094}, {x -> 127.235}, {x -> 130.377}, {x -> 133.518},
          {x -> 136.66}, {x -> 139.802}, {x -> 142.943}, {x -> 146.085},
          {x -> 149.226}, {x -> 152.368}, {x -> 155.509}}
```

Essentially, by replacing `Sqrt[E] = x`, you only need to solve for `x + M Tan[x] == 0` and this for positive `M` and `x`. You know that `Tan[x]` changes sign every multiple of `Pi/2 + kPi`. So you know that there is always a root every `]Pi/2 + k Pi, Pi/2 + (k+1) Pi[`. We use Brent's method here, as this ensures to always find a root between a positive and negative value and due to the nature of `Tan[x]` we know that values close to the borders of the respective interval have opposite signs.

We also use `FindRoot` instead of `NSolve` as `NSolve` is designed for polynomials.